# Who is "Luís Vaz de Camões" in portuguese.SE?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

The user ["Luís Vaz de Camões"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-376?tab=general) has a "negative ID number" (`-376`) and apparently doesn't have a linked account with any SE site.

Who is he? And what it his purpose?

---

O usuário ["Luís Vaz de Camões"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-376?tab=general) tem um "numero de ID negativo" (`-376`) e
não tem vínculos com nenhuma comunidade SE aparentemente além do *chat.SE*.

Quem é ele e qual o seu propósito no site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a bot for auto feeds on the chat room.
You can check a bit more info about the current 2 bots (one for the main site and another one for the meta site) in [this link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/25826/portuguese-language?tab=feeds).